# If I upload a local git repo to GitLab, will GitLab show the history from before it was uploaded?

Tags: git, gitlab

If I have had a local git repo on my computer for a few months, with detailed commit records, and I decide to upload it to a server like GitLab or GitHub, will the commits from before uploading it show up on the server, or will it just show when it was uploaded and changes after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will show history from before. I tried it with GitLab and a test repo and it shows all commits, even from before I uploaded it.